# Interference of Sliders in Kivy

Tags: slider, kivy

I'm learning Kivy and currently try to understand the Slider class. I created two sliders. Slider one is supposed to react to on_touch_move only, while slider two should react to on_touch_up and on_touch_down. If I implement this, like I did in the example below, both sliders interfere, i.e. they react to all three event dispatchers. I tried to understand why that is and how to solve the issue, but I can't. Thank you for helping me out.

The sliders.kv file:

```
#: kivy 1.9.0

SliderScreen:

<SliderScreen>:

    Slider:
        min: 0 
        max: 1
        value: 0.75
        step: 0.01
        on_touch_move: root.test_a()


    Slider:
        min: 0 
        max: 1
        value: 0.25
        step: 0.01
        on_touch_up: root.test_b()
        on_touch_down: root.test_c()
```

and main.py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider

class SliderScreen(BoxLayout):
    def test_a(self):
        print("test_a accessed")

    def test_b(self):
        print("test_b accessed")

    def test_c(self):
        print("test_c accessed")        

class SlidersApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SlidersApp().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`on_touch_move`, `on_touch_up` and `on_touch_down` events are captured by `SliderScreen` class and then propagated to all its widgets. According to the [documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#touch-events):

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets recieve the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not.
>
> This can be counter intuitive if you have experience with other GUI
>   toolkits. These typically divide the screen into geometric areas and
>   only dispatch touch or mouse events to the widget if the coordinate
>   lies within the widgets area.
>
> This requirement becomes very restrictive when working with touch
>   input. Swipes, pinches and long presses may well originate from
>   outside of the widget that wants to know about them and react to them.
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
>   events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
>   If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
>   simply check:
>
> ```
> def on_touch_down(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>         # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
>         pass
> ```

Therefore you should use in your code:

```
Builder.load_string("""

<SliderScreen>:
    Slider:
        min: 0 
        max: 1
        value: 0.75
        step: 0.01
        on_touch_move: if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): root.test_a()

    Slider:
        min: 0 
        max: 1
        value: 0.25
        step: 0.01
        on_touch_up: if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): root.test_b()
        on_touch_down: if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): root.test_c()
 """)

class SliderScreen(BoxLayout):
    def test_a(self):
        print("test_a accessed")

    def test_b(self):
        print("test_b accessed")

    def test_c(self):
        print("test_c accessed")
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. I guess I still need to learn to properly search the documentation...